# Bind printers in local machine in to a drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

In my *ASP.Net* web application am using *CrystalReport* for printing.

I want to bind all printers in the client machine to a `DropDownList` for selecting the printer.

If any body knows, please help me

... Thanx in advance....

Comment: You want to bind the printers on the client (browser) or the server ? This is only possible if you want the server ones.

Comment: @Gabriel:I want to bind the printers on the client... for using CrystalReport.PrintToPrinter() function

Comment: @Nithesh on ASP.NET this is not possible, as ASP.NET runs on the Server side, and only markup is sent to the browser, so you can't access client resources.

Comment: @Gabriel: Thank you Gabriel... Is it Possible through JavaScript? Any idea?

Comment: @Nithesh This may only be possible using ActiveX and your code would require full-trust and would only run in IE.

Comment: @Nithesh the only way is through ActiveX, and that is IE and Windows only. The Registry Key that contains the printers is this one HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible neither recommended. (I mean Activex and all might be a possibility but would complicate the things rather than solving the problem at hand).

But thing about if you really want to go with the option of dropdown.

If you go by practical fact, then the moment your user selects print in crystal report window, by default the browser would prompt with it's own Printer's dialog and thereby letting user select appropriate printer to print with.

That should help you to get around what users need. (Assuming that all they need is a choice to select printer).

Answer (score 0):

Import `System.Drawing.Printing` namespace in your application.

Add a `DropDownList` and change its name to `printersList` and write the below code on page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (String printer in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)

        {

            DropDownListprintersList.Items.Add(printer.ToString());

        }
    }   
}
```